# Is there a standard for rendering vectorized graphics on web sites?

Tags: html, image

It seems that w3c supports the svg file format, however not all browsers support it yet. Are there currently any viable options to include vectorized graphics on a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG is really the only widely supported vector format, but you're right that it's not ubiquitous. The most popular option is to use a layer on top of SVG like [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/). It's compatible with any browser you're likely to encounter nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

SVG is the way to go, but you may need to use some additional plugins to ensure wider compatibility.  To be clear, all modern browsers support it, but there are notable 'previous-gen' browsers that don't (ok, just IE & early Android).

Consider [SVGWeb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/), which will allow you to create a cross-platform SVG embed.  I don't totally agree with their methodology (falling back to a Flash renderer if no native support is detected), but it allows you to embed SVG files, unlike RaphaelJS.

The alternative is to user a server-based renderer like Batik, but my experience with Batik is that it is slow as a dog... fine if you have everything cached, but if you need dynamic scaling or things of that nature, you're better off with SVG proper.

Comment: @Joel B Fant - Hey, if you've got a solution, I'm willing to listen.  : )  In my case, I had 100+ complex images getting called by the server at once.  This spooled up the java engine for each request and I wound up with all kinds of timeouts and other less than ideal behavior.

Might have been fine on Linux, but I was forced into a .NET environment.  In the end, we used Inkscape, which was about 60% faster, but still created timeouts.  I suppose somebody could rewrite Batik into an in-proc service, but that didn't exist at the time.

Comment: I'm tempted to just ignore it if their browser doesn't support svg. Maybe there's some css that can set content depending on the browser version?

Comment: I don't think you can skip IE7/8, which make up somewhere between 30 and 35% of usage these days, but that's up to you.  SVGWeb will do what you want.